# How do I open the Office Upload Center manually?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, onedrive

If there's a problem with the Office 365 One drive upload I get a link to open the Upload Center.

How can I open it manually (without the link provided when a problem occurs)?

This is what I mean by Upload Center:
[image: Upload Center Screenshot]

I tried the [suggestions from the Microsoft site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Microsoft-Office-Upload-Center-F08161D9-AB64-4486-AF69-7CD30B34DF71), but I don't have an icon in the notification area nor can I find it going through the start button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only work around I found so far is to uninstall the Office store app and instead going for the desktop installation.

Be careful, **none of the user settings survive** the update process. So make sure to backup everything especially if you added markros to your Office apps, they will be gone as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can search it directly from taskbar Search option:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I stated in my question I already tried the Windows start button (meaning the menu as well as the search option) - it's below the screenshot, maybe you overlooked it.

Comment: This works if the "Desktop-Version" of Office-365 is installed. For the app version this and a few other things did NOT work. To make it work you have to switch to the desktop version (can be downloaded through office.com after signing in).

Comment: As a note, Office Upload Center will be going away this year for all users. By the end of the year it will be replaced with a per-application experience called "Files Needing Attention" https://support.office.com/en-us/article/files-needing-attention-faq-5c944ab8-1dd5-44f3-9dc6-9cd35846f8ab